# Stuck in a not so infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, infinite-loop

I'm very new to JavaScript so please don't attack me for "ignorant" questions.

In my current code, I'm stuck in what seems to be an infinite loop (but not entirely infinite) that eventually ends after maybe 5 times passing through all of my prompts.

```
var authors = [];
                for(var authorName = 0; authorName < books.length; authorName++)
            {
                authors[0]=parseFloat(prompt("Who wrote War and Peace?"));
                authors[1]=parseFloat(prompt("Who wrote Huckleberry Finn?"));
                authors[2]=parseFloat(prompt("Who wrote The Return of the Native?"));
                authors[3]=parseFloat(prompt("Who wrote A Christmas Carol?"));
                authors[4]=parseFloat(prompt("Who wrote Exodus?"));

        }
```

I'm not sure If I'm just not setting the array up correctly or the for loop or what I need to do to get it to go through and populate the array.

Please keep in mind that I'm very new at JavaScript so the most basic, beginner, simple answers would be the best. I'm just trying to get a strong foothold on the basics as of right now. (:

Comment: You've got a `for` loop that iterates through all of your "books".  For each book, your loop asks 5 questions.

Comment: Also, why are you using `parseFloat()` on the result of calling `prompt()` when your questions appear to be asking for names, not numbers?

Comment: You haven't included a question in your...question.

Comment: Not solving your problem, but sometning odd about your naming convention. You have a variable `authorName` which seems to be an int. Why would an int be called `authorName` ?

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense.

@Pointy, I just do it out of habit of always typically using numbers. I hadn't even realized I was doing it.

One requirement is that I'm supposed to have prompts that include the title of the book.. That's where I'm getting confused as to how to make it work.

var books = ["War and Peace", "Huckleberry Finn", "The Return of the Native", "A Christmas Carol", "Exodus"];

Is what I have before what I originally posted. I'm supposed to have that first array, books, and then use the for loop to populate the second array, authors, that is pop. by prompts.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I'm an extreme beginner of JavaScript so I just name things that will remind me of what I'm using them for. In that case, I'm reminding myself that I'm trying to sort out the authorName within that array. What would you personally name it instead. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Amber Well `authorName` by definition would be a string. It's a name of something. An int, should describe some kind of number. It's not like your code won't work with your names, just trying to help out. What I like to do is picture that whatever code I work on, the next guy/gal to work on it is a crazy lunatic murderer. It's a joke, but basically it means to make sure you code is easy to understand for the next guy/gal (in the case he/she is a murderer, might not be good for you if it's hard!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
var bookNames = [
    "War and Peace?",
    "Huckleberry Finn?",
    "The Return of the Native?",
    "A Christmas Carol?",
    "Exodus?"
];

for(var authorName = 0; authorName < books.length; authorName++)
{
   authors[authorName]=parseFloat(prompt("Who wrote " + bookNames[authorName] + "?"));
}
```

This will only trigger 5 times and is a better way to do what you're trying to do. Also, I would change the name of `authorName` to something that better describes what it is.

Comment: Yes!! That is what I'm trying to do although I couldn't make sense of it in my head. Why I ever decided to major in computer programming when I struggle so badly with logic is beyond me. The curse of being better at English but being endlessly fascinated by computers!

The only issue that I'm having now is that it isn't running through at all when I open the file. Like no prompts are coming up. But the logic makes perfect sense and it's what I was trying to sort out all along.

Answer (score 0):

Every line of code in a `for` block runs as many times as specified, in this case `books.length` times. Each time the loop runs the loop counter, in this case `authorName`, is available as a variable with its current value, in this case it will take on values 0 to 4 over 5 iterations.

```
for(var authorName = 0; authorName < books.length; authorName++)
{
  authors[authorName] = prompt("Who wrote " + books[authorName] + "?");
}
```